# How to trigger execution of a PHP file within a PHP file

Tags: php, html

So I have an HTML file that is a basic form. Say

```
<form method="POST" action="test1.php">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Now I have that execute my test1.php file which goes as follows:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
?>
```

So all it is doing is getting the value from the HTML form. Now I have a second PHP file test2.php that needs to get the value from the first test1.php file $name and output it via an echo statement.

I'm new to PHP and am fine with using one PHP file to output values from an HTML form, but I don't know how to approach a second one.

I'm aware that you can use the [include statement](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to carry over the variables and their values, but it didn't seem to work in my instance. I'm almost positive the issue is that I don't have test2.php actually being executed. And I don't know how to approach that. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: This is all I want test2.php to do. $name has to be the same value as retrieved from the HTML form in test1.php

```
    <?php
    echo $name;
    ?>
```

Comment: Show how you incorporated `test2.php`, and show the code in `test2.php`.

Comment: What sense is this supposed to make? Why not send your form to test2.php in the first place, and access the POST parameter in there directly …?

Comment: @CBroe it's a concept for an assignment, but we were conveniently never shown how to do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Just use include your file test2.php inside test1.php:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    include('test2.php');
?>
```

Whenever you include a file using either include() or require(), the file always gets "executed", so maybe there's something else wrong in you code.

### EDIT

test1.php:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    include('test2.php');
?>
```

test2.php:

```
<?php
    echo $name;
?>
```

Comment: So if my test2.php has an include('test1.php'); 

There won't be any issue with the two include statements?

Comment: If you include test1.php in test2.php and you also include test2.php i test1.php, you'll create an infinite include loop :) You have to do either of them, not them both.

Comment: Totally forgot about include_once! Thanks for bringing that up @mistapink :)

Comment: @DiegoGoesBauleo So how do I access the values of the $name variable in test1.php if I cannot include test1.php in test2.php?

Comment: @mistapink Where would I put the include once statement? In test1 or test2?

Comment: @Burninrock24 I've edited my answer to include the source code for both files, is that what you're trying to achieve? In this case you don't need to use include_once(). However, it is used instead of include() to avoid creating an "infinite include loop" since it only includes a file once.

Comment: @DiegoGoesBauleo So the test2.php get's access to test1.php's variables if it is being included? I thought that it was only the other way around. If test2.php does have access to test1.php's variables then I think this method should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting a session in test1, assign the var $name to the session and then picking the session up on test2.

```
 test1.php
  session_start();
  $name = filter_var($_POST['name'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $_SESSION['test1']['name'] = $name;


 test2.php
  session_start();
  $name = $_SESSION['test1']['name'];
```

Try that.

Comment: How do you propose test2.php gets executed, given this scenario, that is, the form is posted to test1.php?

Answer (score 0):

@bloodyKnuckles, Your assignment was left open ended because there are a number of ways you can accomplish what you're looking to do.

```
 include('test2.php');
```

Is one option.  Another would be

```
 header("Location: test2.php");
 exit();
```

Using the header option, $_SESSION variable would work.  If test1.php had any HTML output, you could consider an AJAX call or urlencode() your string.

```
 test1.php
 echo '<a href="test2.php?name=', urlencode($name), '">Click Me</a>';

 test2.php
 $name = $_GET['name'];
```

I'm guessing your assignment task was designed to demonstrate various ways to pass values from script to script.
Good Luck